# Ways to turn a string into an uri

Tags: android, kotlin, uri

there's any other way to turn a string into an uri without using

```
       implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0-rc01' ??
```

this implementation is not compatible with android-support implementations

Comment: You don't need to use this implementation in order to convert string to uri

Comment: Your question is ambiguous, are you trying to convert the string or trying to use this library?

Comment: You can easily do this without  `Core KTX,` use `Uri.parse("your uri")` method